# Lucene Custom Analyzer for indexing and query

Tags: solr, lucene

I am working on lucene 4.7 and trying to migrate one of the analyzers we use in our solr configuration.

```xml
 <analyzer> 
  <charFilter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory"/>
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>  
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" 
            generateWordParts="1" 
            generateNumberParts="1" 
            catenateWords="1"
            catenateNumbers="1"
            catenateAll="0"
            splitOnCaseChange="0"
            splitOnNumerics="0"
            preserveOriginal="1"
    />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
```

But, I just cannot figure out how to use the HTMLStripCharFilterFactory and the WordDelimiterFilterFactory with the configuration as above. Also, for my query in solr my analyzer is as follows, how can i achieve the same in lucene.

```xml
 <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
            ignoreCase="true"
            words="stopwords.txt"
            />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Analysis package documentation](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_7_0/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/package-summary.html) explains how to use a `CharFilter`.  You wrap the reader with it in your overridden `initReader` method.

I'm assuming the problem with your `WordDelimiterFilter` is that you don't know how to set the configuration options you are using?  You construct an int to pass into the constructor by combining the appropriate constants with a binary and (`&`). such as:

```java
int config = WordDelimiterFilter.GENERATE_NUMBER_PARTS & WordDelimiterFilter.GENERATE_WORD_PARTS; //etc.
```

So, in the end you might end up with something like:

```java
//StopwordAnalyzerBase grants you some convenient ways to handle stop word sets.
public class MyAnalyzer extends StopwordAnalyzerBase {

    private final Version version = Version.LUCENE_47;
    private int wordDelimiterConfig;

    public MyAnalyzer() throws IOException {
        super(version, loadStopwordSet(new FileReader("stopwords.txt"), matchVersion));
        //Might as well load this config up front, along with the stop words
        wordDelimiterConfig = 
            WordDelimiterFilter.GENERATE_WORD_PARTS &
            WordDelimiterFilter.GENERATE_NUMBER_PARTS &
            WordDelimiterFilter.CATENATE_WORDS &
            WordDelimiterFilter.CATENATE_NUMBERS &
            WordDelimiterFilter.PRESERVE_ORIGINAL;
    }

    @Override
    protected TokenStreamComponents createComponents(String fieldName, Reader reader) {
        Tokenizer source = new WhitespaceTokenizer(version, reader);
        TokenStream filter = new WordDelimiterFilter(source, wordDelimiterConfig, null);
        filter = new LowercaseFilterFactory(version, filter);
        filter = new StopFilter(version, filter, stopwords);
        filter = new PorterStemFilter(filter);
        return new TokenStreamComponents(source, filter);
    }

    @Override
    protected Reader initReader(String fieldName, Reader reader) {
        return new HTMLStripCharFilter(reader);
    }
}
```

Note:  I've moved the `StopFilter` to after `LowercaseFilter`.  This makes it case insensitive, as long as your stop word definitions are all in lowercase.  Don't know if this is problematic due to the the `WordDelimiterFilter`.  If so, there is a [`loadStopwordSet` method that support case insensitivity](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_7_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/util/StopwordAnalyzerBase.html#loadStopwordSet(boolean,%20java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)), but I, frankly, don't know how to use it.